# Office 2016 only: botched PDF output from Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016

There seems to be a bug in Office 2016¹ affecting footnote numbers both in the text itself as well as in the footer. Loading the same `.docx` file in either Office 2010 or in LibreOffice 6 and then exporting it as a PDF from there both works fine.

Screenshot of a test file as it looks in Word/Writer. Note that the footnotes are labeled "1" through "11" and are displayed correctly everywhere:

> [image: test.docx]

Screenshot of the same test file exported as a PDF using Word's own PDF export feature. Footnotes 1 through 9 are still fine, but the second digit of "10" and "11" has mysteriously moved to the right:

> [image: test.pdf]

Another screenshot of the bottom half of the docment, this time created using FoxIt's PDF printer device. It exhibits the same problem:

> [image: test-foxit.pdf]

I've uploaded the `test.docx` file [here](https://file.io/KmjBSl). Has anyone seen this problem before? Is there any fix or workaround?

---

¹Professional Plus edition 64 bits, in case it matters.

Comment: I presume these Office installations have any and all updates already installed?

Comment: Wow, good point! Indeed, "non operating-system updates" were turned off on that machine. Enabled and waiting for them to install. It'll be a while...

Comment: Okay, they are all installed now and the problem is indeed gone. Thank you, Ramhound! If you rephrase your comment into an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.